# Google cloud function - calling another with callback

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm looking at migrating from AWS to Google Cloud and there's a few concepts which are alien to me and I can't find much information online. With AWS you have the ability for one lambda to call another lambda programmatically, and to wait for a callback. This is promise driven so completely asynchronous and very easy to scale.

With Google cloud functions you don't seem to have this functionality, which is critical for us as we have a microservice running GraphQL and it'll need to be able to call cloud functions in other microservices.

The only approach I can think of is to use cloud pub sub, where GraphQL dispatches an event on a topic, and the event includes a uuid which is generated by GraphQL. The correct microservice is subscribed to that topic, picks up that event, does what it needs to do and then emits a response event on a topic which has the same name as the uuid sent in the first event. The GraphQL microservice then listens to that topic, picks up the response event and then returns the response to the browser.

However, this approach seems convoluted, potentially slow and doesn't scale well (you can only have 1000 topics). Any thoughts on a better solution? I'm amazed there's not more discussion about this online as it seems like a massive failing on Google's part.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to share code between functions is to simply write a module for it, and invoke that module in as many functions as you require.  You can create whatever API you want, and it doesn't cost anything extra to deploy that bit of code in more than one function.  It should also cost less at scale, as you're not paying for a second function invocation, when only one is required.

If you're dealing with HTTP type triggers, you can simply make an HTTP request from one function to the other.

If you actually need to trigger a second function execution that can't be HTTP based, pubsub is the way to go.  But I would agree that it's not a great system for bidirectional communication.

Comment: Sharing code isn't ideal for us as they're different microservices written in different languages. Also seems to defeat the idea of having microservices and it becomes a monolith again. I also thought about http triggers but that'd be a massive performance overhead just because it's http :(

Comment: I don't think you have any other options than the ones here, unfortunately.  If all you need to do is invoke a couple functions by sharing code, I'd accept that "monolith" as the performant solution.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. This might be what ends up making us stay on AWS... it feels so wrong to give the graphql function access to the code from as many microservices as possible, and multiple siloed database connections

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "as many microservices as possible".  I'd imagine that you'd only deploy to it the functionality it needs to complete its task.  If you want efficient, it's best to have all the required code running in the same container instance so it data doesn't have to get continually shuttled across the network.

Comment: So at the moment we have around 15 microservices (around 200 lambda functions across all of them), most of which are JS. I said 'as many as possible' because they're not all written in the same language, so we wouldn't be able to run them all in one function. I understand the performance benefits of putting them in one cloud function, but I now need to consider things like security (data is no longer siloed)

Comment: If you require isolation and multiple languages, HTTP is your only choice. It's not as bad as you think, as you should be able to find a client library that supports keepalives, which should work with Cloud Functions if the connection is retained and reused at the global scope. Lambda might just be doing this anyway behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I guess I'll benchmark and see what the performance is like!